# Circle of fifths diagram with printed music in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, music

There is already a question here about a circle of fifths diagram ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183117/how-to-conceive-a-macro-for-drawing-a-pie-chart-circle-of-fifths)) but I would like to include pictures of staves like this diagram here

[image]

Is this possible to make it all in LaTeX, I heard there are some packages for writing music (but I have no experience with this). Thank you for your advice.

I managed this using an answer from the linked question. Just labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\myangle}{30}
\foreach \nota/\text [count=\sector] in {C/C minor,G/G minor,D/D minor,A/A minor,E/E minor, B/B minor, FS/F$\sharp$ minor, CS/C$\sharp$ minor, GS/G$\sharp$ minor, EF/E$\flat$ minor, BF/B$\flat$ minor, F/F minor} 
    {
        \draw[shorten >=3mm] (0,0) -- ++({(4-\sector)*\myangle+90}:3cm) node (\nota) {\text};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Thank you for posting your efforts as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Nice first question!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Nice question! Using the MusiXTeX package, there is in fact a really elegant solution. The command for assigning the key signature, `\generalsignature{s}`, simply requires a number where `s > 0` is the number of sharps and `s < 0` is the number of flats.

Therefore, we can just create a `foreach` loop that goes from `-6` to `+5`. And using these integers it is straightforward to assign the required angle around a circle, using Ti*k*Z as our drawing tool.

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\CircROne}{4.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CircRTwo}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MusicR}{5.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\InnerLabelR}{3.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\OuterLabelR}{8}

% THE GRID
\draw (0,0) circle (\CircROne);
\draw (0,0) circle (\CircRTwo);
\foreach \X in {0,1,...,12}
    {
    \draw (0,0)--++(75-\X*360/12:\CircRTwo);
    }
\draw [fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);

% THE MUSIC
\foreach \X in {-6,...,5}
    {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(90-\X*360/12:\MusicR)},xshift=-0.3cm]
        \clip (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) node 
            {
            \begin{music}
            \generalsignature{\X}
            \nostartrule
            \startextract
            \notes\en
            \zendextract
            \end{music}
            };
    \end{scope}
    }

% INNER LABELS
\foreach \X/\KeyText in {-4/F,-3/C,-2/G,-1/D,0/A,1/E,2/B,3/F$\sharp$,4/C$\sharp$} 
    {
    \draw (90-\X*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node {\KeyText~Minor};
    }
\draw (90-5*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {A$\flat$ Minor\\ G$\sharp$ Minor};
\draw (90+6*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {D$\sharp$ Minor\\ E$\flat$ Minor};
\draw (90+5*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {A$\sharp$ Minor\\ B$\flat$ Minor};

% OUTER LABELS    
\foreach \X/\KeyText in {-4/A$\flat$,-3/E$\flat$,-2/B$\flat$,-1/F,0/C,1/G,2/D,3/A,4/E} 
    {
    \draw (90-\X*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node {\KeyText~Major};
    }
\draw (90-5*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {B Major\\ C$\flat$ Major};
\draw (90+6*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {F$\sharp$ Major\\ G$\flat$ Major};
\draw (90+5*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {D$\flat$ Major\\ C$\sharp$ Major};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A rotating circle of fifths...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\foreach \Y in {0,2.5,...,357.5}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\CircROne}{4.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CircRTwo}{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MusicR}{5.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\InnerLabelR}{3.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\OuterLabelR}{8}

\path [use as bounding box] (-9,-9) rectangle (9,9);

% THE GRID
\draw (0,0) circle (\CircROne);
\draw (0,0) circle (\CircRTwo);
\foreach \X in {0,1,...,12}
    {
    \draw (0,0)--++(\Y+75-\X*360/12:\CircRTwo);
    }
\draw [fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);

% THE MUSIC
\foreach \X in {-6,...,5}
    {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\Y+90-\X*360/12:\MusicR)},xshift=-0.3cm]
        \clip (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) node {
            \begin{music}
            \generalsignature{\X}
            \nostartrule
            \startextract
            \notes\en
            \zendextract
            \end{music}
            };
    \end{scope}
    }

% INNER LABELS
\foreach \X/\text in {-4/F,-3/C,-2/G,-1/D,0/A,1/E,2/B,3/F$\sharp$,4/C$\sharp$} 
    {
    \draw (\Y+90-\X*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node {\text~Minor};
    }
\draw (\Y+90-5*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {A$\flat$ Minor\\ G$\sharp$ Minor};
\draw (\Y+90+6*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {D$\sharp$ Minor\\ E$\flat$ Minor};
\draw (\Y+90+5*360/12:\InnerLabelR) node [align=center] {A$\sharp$ Minor\\ B$\flat$ Minor};

% OUTER LABELS    
\foreach \X/\text in {-4/A$\flat$,-3/E$\flat$,-2/B$\flat$,-1/F,0/C,1/G,2/D,3/A,4/E} 
    {
    \draw (\Y+90-\X*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node {\text~Major};
    }
\draw (\Y+90-5*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {B Major\\ C$\flat$ Major};
\draw (\Y+90+6*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {F$\sharp$ Major\\ G$\flat$ Major};
\draw (\Y+90+5*360/12:\OuterLabelR) node [align=center] {D$\flat$ Major\\ C$\sharp$ Major};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's really awesome!

Comment: You're very good is to super vote your answer as the previous ones.

Comment: Can one go *too far* with Tikz? A question that I never considered until reading answers like this in Tex.SE. Take a vote!

Comment: Gorgeous, but, ya know, sometimes it's really a ton easier just to create an image file and embed it in your document.    https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Just inserting the original image would have been easier I guess... but in this circumstance, I would like to - at a minimum - have the diagram made from vector graphics and have the labels match the font of my document. In which case, this TikZ and MusiXTeX solution is actually surprisingly quick and easy! :)

Comment: @Milo just wanted to comment and say thanks for this elegant solution!

Comment: @Milo thank you very much for this code! I've taken the liberty to continue on this and create a circle of fifths with modes and chord-finder: https://github.com/ronligt/circle_of_fifths